# Kivy - Get Image ROI Coordinates

Tags: python, image-processing, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on an application in which I want to load an image and select the ROI of a region. On selection, the start and end coordinates are displayed. Using widget I'm able to get the coordinate of selection(mouse down and mouse up) of the Kivy application. But, what I exactly need is the exact coordinates of the image. Is there is any way to get the ROI of the image?

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import *

class TouchInput(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TouchInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_pos = [0, 0]
        self.end_pos = [0, 0]
        self.img_path = 'img.jpg'

    def but_press(self):
        print("But is pressed!")

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Load Image
            self.img = Image(source=self.img_path)
            self.img.allow_stretch = True
            self.img.keep_ratio = True
            self.img.size = self.size

            # Position set
            self.img.pos = (0, 0)
            self.img.opacity = 1


            self.start_pos = [touch.x, touch.y]
            print("Start pos:", self.start_pos)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        rect_size = [10, 10]
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Load Image
            self.img = Image(source=self.img_path)
            self.img.allow_stretch = True
            self.img.keep_ratio = True
            self.img.size = self.size
            # Position set
            self.img.pos = (0, 0)
            self.img.opacity = 1
            self.end_pos = [touch.x, touch.y]
            # print("End pos  :", self.end_pos)

            if self.start_pos == self.end_pos:
                print("Same position")

            elif (self.start_pos[0] < self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] < self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Top Right")
                rect_start_point = self.start_pos
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 143 / 255, 165 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] < self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] > self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Bottom Right")
                rect_start_point = [self.start_pos[0], self.end_pos[1]]
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(23 / 255, 143 / 255, 54 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] < self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Top Left")
                rect_start_point = [self.end_pos[0], self.start_pos[1]]
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 93 / 255, 65 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] > self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Bottom Left")
                rect_start_point = self.end_pos
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 45 / 255, 34 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            else:
                print("Same Axis")


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        rect_size = [10, 10]
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Load Image
            self.img = Image(source=self.img_path)
            self.img.allow_stretch = True
            self.img.keep_ratio = True
            self.img.size = self.size
            # Position set
            self.img.pos = (0, 0)
            self.img.opacity = 1

            self.end_pos = [touch.x, touch.y]
            print("End pos  :", self.end_pos)

            if self.start_pos == self.end_pos:
                print("Same position")

            elif (self.start_pos[0] < self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] < self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Top Right")
                rect_start_point = self.start_pos
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 143 / 255, 165 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] < self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] > self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Bottom Right")
                rect_start_point = [self.start_pos[0], self.end_pos[1]]
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(23 / 255, 143 / 255, 54 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] < self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Top Left")
                rect_start_point = [self.end_pos[0], self.start_pos[1]]
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0] - self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1] - self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 93 / 255, 65 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.end_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] > self.end_pos[1]):
                print("Bottom Left")
                rect_start_point = self.end_pos
                rect_size = [abs(self.start_pos[0]-self.end_pos[0]), abs(self.start_pos[1]-self.end_pos[1])]

                print("Pos:", self.start_pos, "Size:", rect_size)
                Color(rgba=(100 / 255, 45 / 255, 34 / 255, 0.6))
                self.rect = Rectangle(pos=rect_start_point, size=(rect_size))

            else:
                print("Same Axis")

class TouchApp(App):
    def clear_canvas(self,obj):
        self.ROI.canvas.clear()

    def build(self):
        Parent = BoxLayout()
        self.ROI = TouchInput()
        Parent.add_widget(self.ROI)
        but = Button(text="clear", size_hint_x=0.2)
        but.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        Parent.add_widget(but)
        #self.load_kv("overlay.kv")

        return Parent

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TouchApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using ROI to mean here?

Comment: ROI means Region Of Interest in image processing. Actually, the need is to click and drag to select on the Image region that is in interest.

Comment: @nathancy I checked the code. That code gives the coordinates of the App, not the image.What I need is to select on the image, not on the app. Let's assume if the image is 1920x1080, it is resized according to the app's height and width. That resize should not happen and also I want to crop(or get coordinates of) a particular region of the original(full resolution) image.

Comment: @Prabakar yes that app allows you to select the ROI using the mouse. Remove the resize in the code if you want to use the original dimensions

Comment: @nathancy I tried Scale=False. Still, the image is resized to the app bounds.

Comment: @Prabakar remove the `cv2.resize` line